# Any way to optimize my solution for a faster and more elegant approach?

Tags: php, mysql

In mySQL, I have a column `near_to` where I save entries like `Public Transportation,Business center`

On the frontend I want to display some icons based on these entries.
For example an icon when there is `Public Transportation` inside the field, or `Business Center` or `Fitness Center` and so on.

This is my solution so far. My question is, is there any way to make this faster and more elegant?

```
if (strpos($req['near_to'],'Pub') !==false) {
    echo '<li>public transportation icon</li>';
}
if (strpos($req['near_to'],'Fitn') !==false) {
    echo '<li>fitness icon</li>';
}
if (strpos($req['near_to'],'Busi') !==false) {
    echo '<li>business icon</li>';
}
```

Comment: Using some kind of mapping is usually better solution but if its just for those icons there is no point to change your script...

Comment: @Svetlio basically this case is about 5 icons only. So you suggest to proceed with as it is?

Comment: Absolutely no point to make any logical changes if this is for 5 icons only..

Comment: Are the icons mutually exclusive? Can there be two Icons for same entity?

Comment: Convert pub ,Fitn and so on to array and use in_array().Probably is a lot faster than strpos but for 3 locations you wont gain much

Comment: @Mihai can you show me how please?

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib All icons are different. None icon will be used twice

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Ok then Use `IfElse() Ladder` It shall save you some CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

I made up a little snippet with preg_replace. This way you can define the mapping in one array and get the final result in one statement by running preg_replace on the array itself.

```
<?php 

$subject = "Public Transportation";
//$subject = "Business center";

$patterns = array(
    "/Pub.*/" => "<li>public transportation icon</li>",
    "/Fitn.*/" => "<li>fitness icon</li>",
    "/Busi.*/" => "<li>business icon</li>"
    );

$html = preg_replace(array_keys($patterns), array_values($patterns), $subject);

echo($html);
```

**UPDATE**
if you wanna match subjects for more than one of the patterns, than the pattern key must be different. The keys in the patterns array in the above example match the whole string, therefore only one icon will be returned as you said in your comment.

If we change the patterns as below, you'll see multiple icons in the html results. I assumed that the strings are constant and they are separated by ',', where ',' is optional, hence the '?' in the pattern.

```
<?php 

$subject = "Public Transportation,Fitness Center,Business Center"; //$subject = "Business center";

$patterns = array(
    "/Public Transportation,?/" => "<li>public transportation icon</li>",
    "/Fitness Center,?/" => "<li>fitness icon</li>",
    "/Business Center,?/" => "<li>business icon</li>"
    );

$html = preg_replace(array_keys($patterns), array_values($patterns), $subject);

echo($html);
```

The above will return

```
<li>public transportation icon</li><li>fitness icon</li><li>business icon</li>
```

Comment: Hi thank you. in the case that the `$subject` is `Public Transportation,Fitness Center`, it does not show both icons... only the first

Comment: I see, I updated the answer accordingly. I did not get this requirement first, sorry.